# Mysql count function error with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count the rows in a gallery table with this code:

```
function count_product_gallery($Product_ID)
{
    global $kapcs;

    $count_sql = "SELECT COUNT (gallery_id) AS ennyi_kep FROM gallery WHERE gallery_termek_id = '$Product_ID'";
    $count = mysqli_query($kapcs, $count_sql);
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count);

    echo $fetch['ennyi_kep'];
}
```

I use the function like this:

```
<a tab="#galeria">Gallery(<?php count_product_gallery($id); ?>)</a>
```

On the site, it doesnt echo out nothing, and when i run it in phpmyadmin, i get this error:

**#1630 - FUNCTION COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual**

Comment: you've got a space between `COUNT` and the opening `(`

Comment: Try to use `prepared statements` to prevent your query from sql injection

Comment: yes, remove space after COUNT

Comment: Since it's just a TYPO problem of extra space, i will recomend to delete this question.

Comment: Delete it, i fixed my code so it doesnt matter. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without space after COUNT:

```
SELECT COUNT(gallery_id) AS ennyi_kep FROM gallery WHERE gallery_termek_id = '$Product_ID'"
```

Answer (score 0):

please replace:
$count_sql = "SELECT COUNT (gallery_id) AS ennyi_kep FROM gallery WHERE gallery_termek_id = '$Product_ID'";

TO 
$count_sql = "SELECT COUNT(gallery_id) AS ennyi_kep FROM gallery WHERE gallery_termek_id = '$Product_ID'";

Comment: i think space in btwn  COUNT function and () is create issue.